# Access and modify iframe content from own domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, iframe, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.0 application with AngularJS for frontend. I want to load a pdf (served by own application) in an iframe. Upon a button press, I want to access the content in the pdf and modify it. Currently, I'm displaying the pdf correctly on the page. However, on the mouse click, I'm not able to access its contents. Why can't I access its contents?

I've been trying out many things for hours. This shouldn't be a cross-domain issue, since my own application is serving the content.

In conf/routes:

```
GET     /getRealPdf                      @main.source.PdfGetter.getRealPdf
```

In the Controller PdfGetter.java:

```
public Result getRealPdf() throws IOException {
  byte[] bytes = loadFile("/home/me/test.pdf");
  response().setContentType("application/pdf");
  return ok(bytes);
}
```

In display.scala.html:

```js
var myApp = {};
myApp.module = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.module.controller('MyController',['$scope', '$http', '$sce', MyController]);

function MyController($scope, $http) {
  var controller = this;
  this.name = "My Controller";

  this.highlight = function(text) {
    console.log("document domain: " + document.domain);
    var pdfIframe = document.getElementById("myPdf");
    console.log("pdfIframe: " + pdfIframe);
    console.log("iframe contentDocument: " + leasePdfIframe.contentDocument);
    console.log("iframe document: " + leasePdfIframe.document);
    console.log("iframe name: " + leasePdfIframe.name);
    console.log("iframe src: " + leasePdfIframe.src);
    console.log("iframe srcdoc: " + leasePdfIframe.srcdoc);

    // Below was attempt for when I used embed
    //  var svgDoc = leasePdfIframe.getSVGDocument();
    //  console.log("svgDoc: " + svgDoc);

    // This throws error (cannot access document)!!!
    var d = leasePdfIframe.contentWindow.document;
    
//  console.log("d.innerHtml: " + d.innerHtml);
  }
}
```

```html
<div x-ng-app="myApp" x-ng-controller="MyController as viewer" class="container-fluid">
  <div>
    <iframe src="getRealPdf" id="myPdf" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
<!--      <object data="getRealPdf" type="application/pdf" id="myPdf"></object> -->
<!--      <embed src="getRealPdf" type="application/pdf" id="myPdf"></embed> -->
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="myName" x-ng-click="viewer.highlight('someString')">

</div>
```

If it's any help, what's printed from the console.logs is the following:

> document domain: localhost
>   pdfIframe: [object HTMLIFrameElement]
>   iframe contentDocument: null
>   iframe document: undefined
>   iframe name:
>   "iframe src: http://localhost:9000/getRealPdf"
>   iframe srcdoc:

Comment: What do you think you can do with an adobe plugin or the Chrome PDF renderer? You do not have access to the PDF itself unless you use plugin methods

Comment: What I want to do with the pdf ultimately is to highlight some text on it. When the PDF is rendered right now, I can see the text in the PDF in certain tags. I guess there are two issues.

First, shouldn't I at least be able to access the DOM within the iframe using my current approach? Other places I've seen online have been able to, but I can't.

Second, I'm not sure whether I should be able to modify. What plugins do you have in mind?

Comment: Your PDF is not at all part of your DOM when rendered. To modify a pdf you would have to be able to create it yourself on the client and rewrite it with the changes. Only special tools like Acrobat Pro can edit a pdf in situ